# FB.ui Sharing on Facebook - Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

FB.ui does not open any pop-up/dialog box.
Basically nothing happens. I get also no console error.
Below is my code. I have checked Stackoverflow and other links below to find help. But nothing helps.
I have checked both in localhost and on server but same issue

```
        function postToWallUsingFBUi()
            {   
                var share = {
                    method: "feed",
                    name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!",
                    link: "http://www.google.com/",
                    picture: 'http://i294.photobucket.com/albums/mm92/jsolawis/Feature-Graphic.png',
                    caption: "Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus.",
                    description: "Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram."
                };

                FB.ui(share, function(response){});
            }
```

My FB.login function that i call:

```
FB.login(function(response){
    // do something
},
{scope: 'email, publish_actions, publish_stream'});
```

http://debugmode.net/2012/06/25/sharing-on-facebook-using-javascript/
http://www.joshmorony.com/posting-to-a-facebook-wall-with-phonegap-the-javascript-sdk/

Comment: You don’t need to login and ask for any permissions to post via Feed dialog. As to what the actual issue is here, seems impossible to say with just the code fragments shown – so show a live example please.

Comment: also, publish_stream is deprecated and makes no sense in combination with publish_actions anyway.

Comment: Check there's no errors in the console. It's possible your Site URL is incorrect.

Comment: 1. What is the correct facebook sdk sope for FB.ui?
is it "publish_actions" or "publish_stream"? 
Do I need app approval from Facebook before I can use FB.ui for users to post messages?


2. @Chris Houghton
I don't understand your url comment

3. I checked the console. No error. 
It just seems FB.ui does not run in my case

4. But FB.api runs fine (I don't have official approval yet but it posts to my dev faceboook account)
Thus, am surprised why FB.ui does not run/open the pop-up window